# Visual Studio 2010 Professional Play Button Disabled

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, debugging, windows-phone

I'm having problems with one of my projects in VS2010 Pro, it won't allow me to hit the "debug" play button at the top of the screen, it's been disabled, when I open other projects or start new ones it's enabled on the new project / other project, however, it's disabled on the one project, I don't know what I changed (it's been awhile since I opened this as it pissed me off last time I opened it), what can I do to re-enable the "play" button? (debug), this is a Windows Phone 7 project and I was messing with the .csproj code.

Edit:

The menu-items have been disabled "Start Debugging: F5" doesn't work, as well.

Thank you.

Comment: Are you sure it's not already running? Can you stop it? Shift-F5

Comment: +1 For the resolution of god-awful frustrating situation.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Make sure you do not have Multiple Startup Projects enabled per this [MSDN Forum Link](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/vsdebug/thread/cb10e83a-70b6-43b4-9527-dc5ce9115dcf)

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I'm new to 2010 edition, and I ran into this frustrating god-awful situation, but this answer resolved the whole calamity.

Answer (score 4):

Make sure you have a Startup Project selected. Right click on one of your runnable projects and select "Set as StartUp Project".

Comment: Thanks, you and Mark Hall were right, I had another project selected.

Answer (score 0):

One of the reasons may be that you set your project to compile as library.

There is an easy way to get out - just start new project, then copy all you code/resource files from old project folder to new one, and add them to the new project in visual studio..

Comment: Good idea, though for me Visual Studio let's me try to run a class library and instead tells me that "A project with an Output Type of Class Library cannot be started directly."

Answer (score 0):

Try this

Go to "Project Properties..." >> Compile >> Advanced Compile Options... 
and Change Generate Debug Info: to "Full".